# mvc pattern: two models and one view, where is better create function?

Tags: php, yii, yii2

I can't to decide which model should have a method. So lets see on the code below:

```
class Model1 {
    $value;
}

class Model2 {

}
```

I render a view from controller "belongs" to Model2. This view was created in general to display attributes from Model2, and secondary goal for view - display $value from several Model1. Where is better to create this function, in Model1 or Model2.

```
function getValues($model2Id)
{
     return (array) Model1::find()->where('Model2id' = $model2Id)
}
```

If I create it in Model2, function will take no  one argument. If I create in Model1 function will be static.
**UPD** I also need to use like that function, but from Model3. Only one difference in where('model3Id' = $model3Id).

Comment: Use a trait maybe. You can place them in whatever class you want.

Comment: trait? what do you mean?

Comment: [`Trait`](https://php.net/manual/ro/language.oop5.traits.php) it's like class method, except independent from any class. Can be inserted where needed.

Comment: Have you looked into using Yii2's behaviors? http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-concept-behaviors.html Here's a comparison to traits, as well: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-concept-behaviors.html#comparing-behaviors-with-traits

Comment: function in Model2 or  Model1 will be different in implementation. Model2 knows its id, and can use it directly $this->id

Comment: learn to use relations

Comment: Also it makes no sense to create a static function in the model, you might as well create the static function for a model named Bob. it makes as much sense as what you are asking.

Answer (score 1):

Your description resembles a structure master / detail where an instance of the master model are related multiple instances of a model detail. In these cases the function is normally placed in the Master model.

Comment: Good answer, but would be better if you added some examples related to the original question to provide practical guidance for the poster.